# "to the benefit of" VS "for the benefit of"

Tags: prepositions

> 1. Bringing both organizations together allows us to capitalize on the best of both companies, **to** the benefit of facilities across China and beyond.”
> 2. Bringing both organizations together allows us to capitalize on the best of both companies, **for** the benefit of facilities across China and beyond.”

If I want to convery the meaning "to the advantage of facilities across China and beyond", which one is a fit?

Comment: and yet the corresponding antonym is [to the detriment of](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/to%20the%20detriment%20of)... go figure, that's English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using "to the benefit" simply means that there is a consequence of the capitalization that is beneficial to China and beyond. This seems like the better choice from the perspective of a native speaker.

Using "for the benefit" implies that the beneficial outcome across China and beyond was the explicit intention of the capitalization. In some contexts the two phrases will have approximately the same meaning, but I would avoid it here. Presumably there are other internal reasons for the capitalization (such as increased profit, higher output, etc.), and the benefit to China and beyond is a happy side effect.